# C# RestSharp Returning Blank Request

Tags: c#, restsharp

i'm new to C# and trying to use RestSharp to make an API request to Pay360

I have the request working in PostMan perfectly however when i add that to my project nothing appears in the console.

I have even tried here https://dotnetfiddle.net/obAJSf
can anyone point me in the right direction as to why i cant see the json response in the console

Comment: I think you need to provide some more information, perhaps a code sample?

Comment: And also, can you provide the request that you provide with PostMan with the response?

Comment: If you print the content of response.ErrorMessage, you'll see the error: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Comment: Never used RestSharp, but according to your code and the [documentation](https://restsharp.dev/usage/parameters.html#request-body), you use the wrong method to add the body to the request. Also it would be much wiser, to create an object with the corresponding properties for the body and use `AddJsonBody()`.

Comment: Have you checked https://restsharp.dev/get-help/faq.html#empty-response ?

Comment: so according the the error  i need to add this to the web.config under system.web :  <trust level="Full" />  but i cant do that on dotnetfiddle

i have also updated the method for sending the json and still not working